# Run Xamarin.UITest on iOS on local simulator WITHOUT test cloud?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

Every time I run my Xamarin.iOS UITest, I get an error:

```
System.Exception : Unable to contact test backend running in app. A common cause is that the app is not properly linked with Calabash. Please verify that it includes the Calabash component.
```

But I don't want to connect to any test backend - I want to run it locally on my iPhone Simulator (I *am* on a Mac).  I created a basic Xamarin project, added a UITest project, and am able to run Android with no issues.  I did install the Xamarin.TestCloud.Agent package, and included the `#if ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD` block in AppDelegate.cs (just in case it was required for local testing), but I can't get it to run locally.

Interestingly, the simulator DOES load, and so does the app.  But the test never actually starts (it will fail on `.StartApp()`).  I also get the Mac alert 'Do you want the application "DeviceAgent-Runner.app" to accept incoming network connections?' to which I answer Allow, because why not.

I'm so confused...

Thanks!

edit: this is my app `ConfigureApp` code:

```
return ConfigureApp
    .iOS
    .Debug()
    .AppBundle ("../../../Kroe761Test.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone 11-13.5/kroe761.iOS.app")
    .DeviceIdentifier("D68D731A-775F-4BF1-8EF6-13F3FEDD00CF") // iphone 11 pro 
    .StartApp();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed adding ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD; in your project options.

[image]

Follow all the steps from here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/get-started-xamarin-forms

Clean and build your project. It should be working.